# Is there a way to inject List<TypeA> in a constructor using the Bootstrap file and Unity Container?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working on Unity container to inject dependencies through a constructor , I was able to resolve all other types apart from the List of objects.
I tried to register the type as

```
container.RegisterType<IList<TypeA>,List<TypeA>>();
```

in the `Bootstrap.cs` file.

When I try to resolve the type , I am getting this exception:

> The type List'1 has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to
>   disambiguate. At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving
>   System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Test.Models.TypeA],(none) (mapped
>   from System.Collections.Generic.IList'1[Test.Models.TypeA],
>   (none))

Exception type: InvalidOperationException

Please suggest me to inject a list of objects using Unity Container.

Comment: Does `TypeA` has any dependency on its constructor?

Comment: No TypeA has no dependency on its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity tries to use the constructor with the most parameters and then resolve and inject dependencies.  Since `List<>` has 2 constructors that take 1 parameter, Unity can't decide which constructor to use.

You can use an `InjectionFactory` to tell Unity how to resolve this and make it use the 0 parameter constructor.

```
container.RegisterType<IList<TypeA>>(new InjectionFactory(x => new List<TypeA>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Unity won't resolve lists automatically. I hope that someone will be able to prove me wrong and provide a better answer than this one, but this is the way that I have done it.

Say, you have a service named SomeService that requires an `IList<TypeA>` in its constructor. The first thing you need to do is to ensure that every instance of `ITypeA` is registered as a *named instance*. The most sensible thing to do is to use the name of the concrete type as the name.

```
container.RegisterType<ITypeA, TypeA1>(typeof(TypeA1).Name);
container.RegisterType<ITypeA, TypeA2>(typeof(TypeA2).Name);
container.RegisterType<ITypeA, TypeA3>(typeof(TypeA3).Name);
```

Now that we have the types registered as named instances, we need to register SomeService and give it an explicit constructor.

```
container.RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeService>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedArrayParameter<ITypeA>(container.ResolveAll<ITypeA>().ToList())
));
```

The location of the list must be in the same location as the location of the parameter in the constructor declaration. Also, all of the parameters *must be supplied* explicitly.

Also, the error indicates that you have *more than one* constructor in your service. This is an anti-pattern known as [bastard injection](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). One of the main reasons why it is considered anti-pattern is that DI containers often have problems working out which constructor to call, like in this case.

Comment: I think you answered "how to resolve list of objects of particular type" when question looks like "how to resolve instance of `List<ParticularType>`"... May deserve a note in the beginning of the answer. (Not in any way wrong answer, just another valid interpretation of the question as asked).